Do I really need multimedia codecs in the server?
I can't find a good answer for my question, do I as a developer and system administrator, need to install ffmpeg, faac, alac,wavpack, vorbis, lame, imagemagick and other mutlimedia codecs for running and playing music, or making a radio stream for music in the web development, or working with images like imagemagick.
So when I need to install multimedia codecs, and when I don't need them?

You generally don't need them for ordinary server use, which is why Ubuntu Server does not include them.

You can't find a good answer because the only real answer here is: try for yourself. We can't predict what music exactly you are going to play, or how you're going to stream something, or which images you're going to work with. Only you know that.

You need the audio and video tools listed if you want to examine, view, edit, play, record, or otherwise manipulate image, video and audio files of the formats they support.
If part of your development involves audio or video, including preparing them for presentation on a website, you might want those tools.  (Most websites at least use images.)
If you are not working with images, audio or video in any way, then you don't need those tools.
